# Change javascript code to jquery code, How is it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want change following javascript code to jquery code, How is it?

With done change `hourOffset` in date `3, 21` and `9, 22`.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/zJRDC/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var interval = self.setInterval("clock()", 1000);
    function clock() {
        var date = new Date();
        var hourOffset = 3;
        date.setUTCHours(date.getUTCHours(), date.getUTCMinutes());
        var time = date.getTime();
        date.setUTCFullYear(date.getUTCFullYear(), 3, 21);
        var dstStart = date.getTime();
        date.setUTCFullYear(date.getUTCFullYear(), 9, 22);
        var dstEnd = date.getTime();
        if (time > dstStart && time < dstEnd){ hourOffset = 4;}
        date.setUTCHours(date.getUTCHours() + hourOffset, date.getUTCMinutes() + 30);
        var output = date.getUTCHours() + ":" + date.getUTCMinutes() + ":" + date.getUTCSeconds();
        document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = output
    }
    </script>
<div id="clock"></div>​
```

Comment: Do you have any good reason to replace this simple code snippet with jQuery...? Using jQuery doesn't make a code more awesome. Your current code uses well-supported methods. There is absolutely no need to use jQuery.

Comment: JavaScript is a programming language, jQuery a web browser framework (which itself is programmed in JavaScript). jQuery is not a language. Apart from that, your DST calculation is wrong.

Comment: Why you need change it beutiful code? :-)

Comment: what's the advantage of using jQeury you expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's precisely one line of that where jQuery might apply:

```
document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = output
```

which with jQuery could be

```
$("#clock").html(output);
```

That uses [`$`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery) to look up the element, which includes a workaround for a [bug in `getElementById` in earlier versions of IE](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/by-any-other-name-would-smell-as-sweet.html), and then uses the [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html) method to set the markup on the element (which is very like setting `innerHTML` — again, though, with some workarounds for problematic bits in some cases; they probably don't apply to this specific code).

---

Note that jQuery is just a framework written in JavaScript. It smooths over some browser differences dealing with the DOM, and provides a lot of handy utility functionality, but it's not a thing separate from JavaScript. You write JavaScript code, and you optionally *use* jQuery in it (just like any other library).

Comment: @jenniferJolie: That's because you're loading jQuery using `onload`, but running your code earlier. If you load jQuery early enough that your code doesn't try to use it before it's there (or conversely set off your code later), it works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/zJRDC/2/

Answer (score 1):

if your code works. you don't really need jquery. unless you want to create re-usable function or your custom plugin.

a quick sample to use clock() as jquery plugins (didn't test)

```
(function( $ ){

  $.fn.myClock = function(timeout) {

    var interval = setInterval("clock()", timeout);

    function clock() {
        //..calculate date output
        var output = //...
        this.html(output)
    }
  };
})( jQuery );
```

then to use your plugin

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#clock').myClock(1000);
}
```

see [Plugins/Authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) and [learn-how-to-create-your-own-jquery-plugin](http://www.myinkblog.com/learn-how-to-create-your-own-jquery-plugin/)

Answer (score 0):

JQuery is already done with JavaScript . Nothing to convert because JQuery is not a language ;).